# how to create screen and navigations for two different users in react native

Tags: react-native, navigation, multi-user

I have two types of users in my app. one is health partners and other one is customers. so
Lets Assume I have 4 screen.

1. Home Screen
2. Menu Screen
3. Notification Screen
4. Account Screen

so I have different UIs in all 4 screens means for health partner Home screen look different and for customers it Should look different.

so what is the best way to do that. Should I create separate Screen And separate Stacks for two users. means then there is two stacks and 8 screens. or what you think please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Save user kind in login as `AsyncStorage` and check that in all of your screen and then initialize UI changes for that pages

Comment: ok so no need to crate separate page. instead I can condition in screen if user is Health partner then render this <View> if not then render this <View> .. right ??

Comment: Yes, you can do it this way if the UI's are somewhat similar to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach,
When you are onboarding a user be it while login or otherwise, pass a parameter in navigation and then apply the appropriate style based on the type of user.

Here is the working example: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@theketan2/vigorous-pudding)

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

function Login({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Login Screen</Text>
      <View style={{ margin: 10 }}>
        <Button
          title="Health Partner"
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home', { type: 'partner' })}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={{ margin: 10 }}>
        <Button
          title="User"
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home', { type: 'user' })}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

function HomeScreen({ route }) {
  let { type } = route.params;
  return (
    <View style={type === 'user' ? styles.user : styles.partner}>
      <Text>{`Home Screen ${type}`}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  user: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'pink',
  },
  partner: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Output:

[image]